# How to compare opposing index values of an array and removing based on a condition with a nested for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a list of Job objects (each Job object consists of an id (integer), a startTime (float), and a finishTime (float)) and I'm trying to remove conflicting job objects. Such that the I'm comparing the end entries with the starting ones and removing the end entries that conflict.

I have my code :

```js
List < Job > sortedJobs = new ArrayList < Job > ();
int SJsize = sortedJobs.size();
for (int i = SJsize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  for (int j = 0; j < SJsize; j++) {
    if ((sortedJobs.get(i).getStartTime() > sortedJobs.get(j).getStartTime() &&
        sortedJobs.get(i).getStartTime() < sortedJobs.get(j).getFinishTime()) ||
      (sortedJobs.get(i).getFinishTime() > sortedJobs.get(j).getStartTime() &&
        sortedJobs.get(i).getFinishTime() < sortedJobs.get(j).getFinishTime())) {
        
      sortedJobs.remove(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me index out of bounds error but if I try to add a i-- everytime it removes an element the loop doesn't seem to compare every element. How do I write it properly? Thanks

Comment: what do you consider a conflicting job in your case?

Comment: the jobs conflict if the start time and/or finish times overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that straightforward to remove elements form the list, when iterating over it. 
Look at this post to examine them:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it

To avoid this problem you can also save elements you want to remove and delete them after iteration is done.

```
        List < Job > sortedJobs = new ArrayList < Job > ();
        int SJsize = sortedJobs.size();
        List<Job> jobsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = SJsize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          for (int j = 0; j < SJsize; j++) {
            if ((sortedJobs.get(i).getStartTime() > sortedJobs.get(j).getStartTime() &&
                sortedJobs.get(i).getStartTime() < sortedJobs.get(j).getFinishTime()) ||
              (sortedJobs.get(i).getFinishTime() > sortedJobs.get(j).getStartTime() &&
                sortedJobs.get(i).getFinishTime() < sortedJobs.get(j).getFinishTime())) {

              //save elements to remove
              jobsToRemove.add(sortedJobs.get(i));
            }
          }
        }

        //actually remove elements, when iteration over list is finished.
        sortedJobs.removeAll(jobsToRemove);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `sortedJobs.removeAll(jobsToRemove);` instead of that second loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decrement i every time you remove an object, because every time you remove an object from a list, the size of the list decreases. So if you don't decrement i, your iterator will try to access elements that don't exist (the list is now shorter).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by conflicting job objects. Anyway, it is not possible to modify a Collection in "standard" loop (after removing some objects size of the Collection gonna change but you will be using it's old size). If you really want to do that you should look at [java.util.Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). However, I'm not sure how it works with nested loops.

Probably the easiest solution would be to created a helper list of the objects you want to delete. In your loop just add those elements to that helper loop. After the loop call `sortedJobs.removeAll(helperList);`

Answer (score 0):

What about just create new list and add not conflicted jobs iterating over given jobs:

```
public static List<Job> retrieveNotConflictedJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
    Collections.sort(jobs);

    Job prvJob = null;
    List<Job> res = new LinkedList<>();

    for(Job job : jobs) {
        if(prvJob == null || prvJob.getFinishTime() < job.getStartTime()) {
            res.add(job);
            prvJob = job;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```